# How to add a photo using the res class?

Tags: graphics, resume

I'm using the [`res`](http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/) class for my resume, but none of the examples show how to add a photo. 
How do I add a 2x2 photo somewhere in the upper corners without breaking the layout? (I'm using example #2 in the link)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the following code to the preamble; instead of `logo` write the name of your photo:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\addphoto}[2]{%
  \smash{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{%
      \raisebox{#1mm}{%
        \hspace{#2mm}\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{logo}%
      }%
     }%
  }%
}
```

Then in the first address write

```
\address{\addphoto{5}{150}%
  {\bf Present Address} \\
   204 Pawling Avenue \\ Troy, NY 12180  \\
   (518) 273-4617 }
```

The two arguments to `\addphoto` are the vertical and horizontal displacements in millimeters. Just play with them until you're satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `textpos` package. It's really convenient.
Example:    (Put this in preamble)

```
    \usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
    \setlength{\TPHorizModule}{30mm}
    \setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
    \textblockorigin{-6mm}{32mm} % start everything near the top-left corner
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
```

Then this portion goes in the document

```
    \begin{textblock}{3}(0,0)
      {\large\bf ABU FAZAL MD SHUMON} \\
      {Address} \\
      {State, Country} \\
      {email} \\
      {\href{url}{link-text}} \\
      {\href{Linkedin URL}{LinkedIn Profile}}
    \end{textblock}
```

To add picture/image in the upper right corner of the image.

```
    \begin{tabular}{ L{7cm}  R{5.48cm} }
            &
      \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{shumon.jpg} \\
    \end{tabular}
```

Hopefully you would get a decent output towards the end. At least that's I got my purpose served.

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{tabular}{l <{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{50mm}c}

\multirow{4}{*}{ \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth, height=30mm]{saeed.jpg}
}\\ &  {Address 1} \\
 & {Street, Country} \\
 & {Tel: }\\
 & {Email:}\\ 
& \\

\end{tabular}
```

Comment: dont use address for res document

Comment: Why not? The documentation allows it.

Comment: A full example would be more helpful.